# Rails: Route Error while trying to update attribute through link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, link-to, update-attribute

ERROR: No route matches [GET] "/bookings/:id/%3E:format"

I want to update an attribute when click on link of  'link_to'..

```
<%= link_to 'Cancel', '/bookings/:id/(.:format)' %>
```

routes.rb

```
put '/bookings/:id/(.:format)' => "bookings#tocancel"
patch '/bookings/:id/(.:format)' => "bookings#tocancel"
```

controller

```
def tocancel
 @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
 @booking.update_attribute(:status, "cancel")
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to @booking, notice: 'Booking was successfully cancelled.' }
  format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @booking }
```

end

Comment: You don't pass the URL format to link_to. You can use the helper method bookings_path and pass the @booking object. Read the (excellent) documentation about it: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: `<%= link_to 'Cancel', 'complete_url/bookings/pass_id_value_here' %>` pass id value in `:id` place.

Comment: <%= link_to 'Cancel', tocancel_booking_path(booking) %>                             ERROR :No route matches [GET] "/bookings/36/tocancel"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a method in bookings controller as:

```
def tocancel
 @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
 @booking.update_attribute(:status, "cancel")
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to @booking, notice: 'Booking was successfully cancelled.' }
  format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @booking }
 end
end
```

Routes for this would be:

```
resources :bookings do
  member do
   get :tocancel
  end
end
```

Cancel link can be created as:

```
link_to "Cancel", tocancel_booking_path(booking.id)
```

Here you should have booking_id passed to cancel link. Now check how you get booking_id on the page where you put this cancel link.
Let me know if any issue.

Comment: getting ERROR: undefined local variable or method `booking_id' for #<#<Class:0x00000003265158>:0x007fe38405a900>

Comment: Can you give me the url of the page where you are adding this link. you need to retrieve booking_id in that page and pass to this cancel link..

Comment: here is the link active.html.erb [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-cw8FVV0gUeSENXWGlrbW1HNVU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The link seems to be right...try passing booking id instead of object something like booking.id

Comment: i passed booking then its takes id but shows no route mathches..ERROR:No route matches [GET] "/bookings/36/tocancel"

Comment: Please make the patch to get routes....as we are not taking any params along with url...so get would work...

Comment: please tell me how can i change it